# Unable to delete apps from iphone 5s

Tags: iphone, itunes

[image]Unable to delete application in iphone5s. There is no 'x' when the icon jiggles. I was able to delete previously until today (17-Jul-16). There was no apps update failure or IOS update failure. IOS version 9.3.2.

I tried to delete from iTunes but Apps are not displayed in iTunes. I am on Windows 10. I had just installed iTunes today, version is 12.4.1.6. Attached itunes screen shot.

Appreciate your help

Comment: did you reboot the phone yet?

Comment: Yes, already turn off and turn on my phone 3 times but the same result. Therefore I installed iTunes to see if there is any apps issue but could not see any apps except the home screen. Not sure what to do next.